# Question about Dedekind domain having Krull dimension 0 or 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, dedekind-domain

I am reading a lemma on Dedekind domain but I have difficulties understanding it, I am bring it up here hoping for help. The original passage is in one big fat paragraph but I broke it down here for your easy reading. Thanks beforehand for all your time and help, let me know if I forget to include any underlying lemmas.

***LEMMA: Dedekind domains have Krull dimension 0 or 1.***

PROOF: (1) Let *R* be a Dedekind domain, let *T* be a nonzero prime ideal of *R*, and let *U* be a maximal ideal of *R* such that *T* $\subseteq$ *U*. We shall see that *T = U*.

(2) Since *R* is assumed to be a Dedekind domain, we obtain from *T $\subseteq$ U* an ideal *V* of *R* such that *T = UV*.

(3) Thus, as *T* is a prime ideal of *R*, *U* $\subseteq$ *T* or *V* $\subseteq$ *T*.

(4) Assume first that *V* $\subseteq$ *T*. Then, as *T = UV*, *T* $\subseteq$ *UT*.

**[Here is my question from #(4): How do you go from *T = UV* to *T* $\subseteq$ *UT* ?]**

(5) Thus, as *T* $\neq${0}, *R* $\subseteq$ *U*; see Lemma below.

**[The lemma referred aboved is this: "Let *R* be a Dedekind domain, and let *U* and *V* be ideals of *R*. Assume that *R* possesses a nonzero ideal *T* with *TU $\subseteq$ TV* . Then *U $\subseteq$ V*." But even after arduous reading, I still don't know how *R* $\subseteq$ *U* is derived in #(5).]**

(6) This contradicts the fact that *U* is a maximal ideal of *R*. Thus, *U* $\subseteq$ *T*.

(7) Thus, as *T* $\subseteq$ *U*, *T = U*.

**[How does *T = U* relate to dimension of 0 or 1?]**

As always, thank you so much for your time and help.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**EDIT:**
Here is how Dedekind domain defined in the text: An integral domain *R* is called Dedekind domain if, for any two ideals *T* and *U* of *R* with *T* $\subseteq$ *U*, there exists an ideal *V* of *R* such that *T* = *UV*.

Comment: If $T=UV$, then $T=UV\subseteq UUV=UT$. If we have shown that $T=U$, then the length of prime ideal chains is at most $2$, so that the Krull dimension is at most $1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Thanks. But perhaps I missed the big picture, how do you get *UV* $\subseteq$ *UUV* in the first place? Thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(4) From $V\subseteq T$ we get $UV\subseteq UT$ and since $T=UV$ ...

(5) Set in your lemma $U=R$ and $V=U$. Note that $TR=T$.

(7) You have actually shown that every non-zero prime is maximal, so you can't have a chain of three primes in $R$.

Comment: Thanks! I clicked the up arrow for you. (a) On #5, how do you derive $TR=T$ in the first place? I think this is the key to understand the entire lemma. (b) On general side, when you read long & complicated lemma like this one, do you use Venn diagram or other mental aid to help your visualization? (Perhaps this is a totally different subject, for that I'm willing to type a new posting so that every response may get credit - do let me know. Thanks again & again.)

Comment: @A.Magnus (a) $T$ is an ideal, so $tr\in T$ for any $t\in T$ and $r\in R$, that is, $TR\subseteq T$. On the other side, for any $t\in T$ we have $t=t\cdot 1_R$, so $t\in TR$. (b) I've never used images for abstract algebraic objects like ideals in a (presumably) Dedekind domain, only the properties they have.

Comment: Thanks again, you have given me second lease on my study.